# How to join N regex patterns into one

Tags: php, regex

I have few patters like these:

```
    $confirm    = '~/[a-z][a-z]/confirm\?hash=[0-9a-zA-Z]+~u';
    $letter = '~/[a-z][a-z]/letter/[0-9a-zA-Z]+~u';
    $tracker   = '~/[a-z][a-z]/(tracker\?hash)=[0-9a-zA-Z]+~u';
    preg_match($confirm, $text);
```

They all work just fine.

How can I join these 3 patterns into one? I have tried with `|` conditional, but it's not working.

I need something like:

```
preg_match ($confirm OR $letter OR $tracker, $text) IF ANY MATCH found ok good
```

Comment: @Kleskowy yes, but i need to find not all matches,if 1st match is found its ok, i need OR condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to put all 3 patterns into one:

```
$pattern = '~/[a-z][a-z]/(confirm\?hash=|letter|tracker\?hash=)[0-9a-zA-Z]+~u';
preg_match($pattern, $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
~/[a-z][a-z]/(?:confirm\?hash=|letter|(tracker\?hash=))[0-9a-zA-Z]+~u
```

You can try this.

Answer (score 0):

My try

```
<?php
$pattern = '~/[a-z][a-z]/ (%s) [0-9a-zA-Z]+~xu';

$subPatterns = array(
    'confirm\?hash=',
    'letter/',
    'tracker\?hash=',
);

$subPatternString = implode(' | ', $subPatterns);

$finalPattern = sprintf($pattern, $subPatternString);

var_dump($finalPattern);
```